# Stream<Optional<List<MyClass>>> how to get a value from MyClass or check if List is empty

Tags: lambda, java-8, option-type

I'm working with lambda expressions. Sometimes I need to go through a declaration like this in order to check if my `List<MyOwnClass>` is empty or get a value from it.

```
Stream<Optional<Stream<Optional<List<MyOwnClass>>>>>
```

The particular case that I'm facing right now is the following declaration:

```
Stream<Optional<List<MyOwnProductClass>>> streamProduct;
```

If I'd have something like this:

`Optional<List<MyOwnProductClass>> optionalProduct`

I could access like this: `optionalProduct.get().isEmpty()` because `get()` is an Optional's method but not sure how to do it with Stream since doesn't exist the same method. For the following declaration:

```
Stream<Optional<List<MyOwnProductClass>>> streamProduct;
```

It's not possible to do something like this: `streamProduct.get().get().isEmpty(); // streamProduct.get() -> Error as it doens't exist that method`

Any idea how I can get what I need? Thanks

Comment: You should fix the code that produce something odd like `Stream<Optional<Stream<Optional<List<MyOwnClass>>>>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do (assuming you have a single element in that stream):

```
streamProduct.findFirst().get().get().isEmpty()
```

but would be the point of `Optional` in this case if you are calling `get` directly? And of course these declarations, well, are awful - I simply have no other words to describe them; start from refactoring this (if it's under your control).

What is the point of wrapping a `List` into an `Optional` - just return an empty List in case no elements are needed and of course wrapping that into a `Stream` makes it even worse, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!!! Actually, I'm trying to analyze a big lambda expression and I started to divide it in order to understand it. That's the reason to have a declaration like above as it's my own one. Thanks

Comment: @William well, I guess that is a good start, but think about it yourself, a `Stream` of a single element, that contains an `Optional` that wraps a List... the very first thing i would do is refactor, once clear what is going on. With proper refactoring things will get *a lot* cleaner. Also, calling `get` directly on an `Optional` is a very bad thing, what if that Optional is actually `empty`?